# Two Certificates when using Identyserver4 with asp.net core webserver?

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, https, ssl-certificate, identityserver4

I am going hosting an webserver and an api with the same application over asp.net core. I am using Identyserver4 to secure the API connections. Do i need a seperate Certificate for the https asp.net core website and the identityserver4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least two separate certificates.
The difference is that your SSL cert must be bound to the host name and trusted for everyone accessing your server, while the signing certificate does not have any special requirements.
See [this article](https://brockallen.com/2015/06/01/makecert-and-creating-ssl-or-signing-certificates/) for further reference and [this question](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2888) as a proof link.
It's not clear from your explanation where you host your main ASP.NET Core web site. If that's another host than where your IdSrv lives, than you need the third(!) cert to enable SSL there too.